# Bounding the rate of change of a function

Tags: calculus, functions

A function is defined by

$$f(x) = x\times \dfrac{\ln 2 - \ln x}{2 - x} $$
$$f(2)=1$$

The problem asks to prove that for $x\in(2,3]$, we have

$$\dfrac{1}{2x} < \dfrac{f(x) - f(2)}{x-2} < \dfrac 14$$

A hint given is the MVT, I tried applying it to $f$ directly, then to $\ln$ but it doesn't yield the sought bounding..

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: This function is not even continuous. Did you mean $f(2)=\frac 1 2$?

Comment: I fixed the expression sorry .